# how to get top 5 amounts from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, web-services, scatter-plot

I have a table and I want to make a graph on the basis of this table.  What should be the Query for doing so.

Currently I want the top 5 amounts from this table; this table has about 8000 records. What will be the query that return top 5 amounts.

This is the table

[image]
Also Recommend
What should be the possible Queries that return two values that makes a graph, from this table.

**Sorry I Have Got the reason behind **

Mysql is reading The column Amount as a string value due to $ sign inside....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT code, amount FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 0, 5;
```

It will return ordered lines by amount that you could store in array. Use ASC instead of DESC for ascending order. Why does the first line contains something that should not be there?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
 SELECT top 5 code, amount FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

It would yield the same result.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 code, amount FROM test_table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select code, 
       amount 
  from table_name 
 where amount in 
       (select distinct amount 
          from table_name 
      order by amount desc limit 5) 
order by amount desc;
```

This will give top five amounts(not 5 rows)
in Mysql "TOP" key word is not there